# Remove test method from com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports

Tags: java, extentreports

I am re-running my failed testng test cases. So I only want to display the passed test or the last ran test in the report. So I want to remove the test method from the com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports

Is there any way that I can do it?

Comment: Are you using a listener to rerun the scenarios? if so can you post the code here? There is an option to remove the test from report based on the test result.